# iOS sharing resetting app orientation

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, sharing

The app has portrait as default orientation within Unity3D. Using the app, nothing goes wrong and rotating the device does not affect the GUI and others.

Using native sharing we first get the sharing window with the "More..." button.

If the user presses the "More..." button while holding the device as horizontally, the new window shows as landscape and the whole app rotates behind. Doing the invert process totally screws the app. We are using Vuforia and the camera feed goes upside down before turning black.

The "More..." button seem to call for a new activity that seem to ask for the current rotation and (for some unknown reasons) also would send a message to the app about the new rotation.

Can I prevent that?

Comment: I would recommend using the latest Facebook SDK (7.0.3 as of August 20th, 2015) which should include a fix for the issue you mention. It was a real bug a while back (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/change-log#150414)

Comment: Despite using Unity we are not using the Facebook SDK for Unity but the one for iOS. But the problem is not related to facebook, I wrongly added the facebook tag (removing it now) as sharing is handled by the OS.

Comment: I have the same problem and just curious have you found the soulution for this issue?

Comment: No, I kinda put the problem on hold for the time being. I tried some more debugging but nothing prints onto the console that is related to the "More..." action. We are using Vuforia and UniWebView and I am thinking one of those may be responsible as they take over the main view of the app.